# macOS Sierra: Install from USB error

Tags: macos, usb, startup, ssd

I have a mid 2015 MacBook Pro that just stopped booting suddenly. Thinking, I'll fix it, I formatted (erased) my hard drive and first tried Internet Recovery which didn't work. Then, using another MacBook, I made a bootable USB, which works great until I actually tried installing the OS. It hangs for like 5 minutes then it shows an error:

```
Failed to retrieve file:///Volumes/Image%20Volume/Install%20macos%20Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg (Error Domain=com.apple.PackageKit.PKFileDownload Code=3)
```

What could be causing the issue and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took it to an Apple Store. The SSD on MacBook was broken causing the failure. It was replaced.

Comment: @nimesh-neema why did you edit my comment?